# Key binding for showing TODO items in Emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, todo

I'm starting to use org-mode, and I'm having problems understanding the key binding for showing TODO items.
In [this section of the beginners tutorial](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org4beginners.html#sec-4) says:

```
C-c C-v – show todos in current document
```

But when I type it, Emacs is expecting me to type more keys...

Where am I supposed to be in the org file in order to make that key binding work?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I'd guess that the tutorial is out-of-date.  `C-c C-v` is a prefix key for Org babel.  Type `C-c C-v C-h` to see the commands under it.  To see the current TODO items in a file, you can use sparse tree commands, like `C-c / t` (see `(info "(org)Sparse trees")`).  You can use the agenda to list all TODO items of a file by restricting the output to the current file with `C-c a < t`, assuming you've bound `org-agenda` to `C-c a` (see `(info "(org)Agenda dispatcher")`).

Comment: `C-c / t` did work. Thanks! The first page match in Google for "[orgmode cheatsheet](http://orgmode.org/orgcard.pdf)" also lists `C-c C-v` as *view TODO items in a sparse tree*. Outdated too?

Comment: Yes, looking more closely: A commit in 2010 (3d8b6de2ad00220e, after the 6.36 release) removed `org-show-todo-tree` from `C-c C-v` (to free it up for Org Babel).  Later, a commit in 2012 (1fb3cca7c08ec1a, after the 7.9.2 release) fixed orgcard.pdf, which still referred to the `C-c C-v` binding.